# Read all the JSON fields through shell script

Tags: shell, json

I have below job lists. I need to prepare a CSV file for Job

```
Name,Status,Last Start,Last End
    Joblists :
    123.load.nw-data.025
    123.load.nw-data.026
    123.load.nw-data.027
    123.load.nw-data.028

curl -s --insecure http://status-api.xyz.net:1234/v1/jobs_status/123?job_name=123.load.nw-data.025
```

o/p :

```
{
    "JobID": "A123123.load.nw-data.025",
    "Job PID": -1,
    "Job Name": "123.load.nw-data.025",
    "Status": "RUNNING",
    "Run Machine": "",
    "Queue": "",
    "Status Time": "2020-10-06 05:30:17",
    "Exit Code": -656,
    "Last Start": "2020-10-06 05:30:17",
    "Last End": null,
}
```

Comment: It appears as if the JSON you get is broken. It contains a trailing comma at the end.

Comment: Yeah that's due to that curl command run with API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you fetched the data into "input.json"

Your data should not contain " or ,
if it does you better  parse that with a different language.

You can have only 1 dataset per file, no arrays.

```
#!/bin/sh
(
        # Title line
        grep : input.json | cut -d : -f 1 | tr '\n' ','
        echo ''
        # Data line
        grep : input.json | cut -d : -f 2- | tr -d '\n'
        echo ''
) |
sed -e 's| *"|"|g' -e 's|", *|",|g' -e 's|,$||'
```